# how to convert byte to string in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, byte

I want to know how to convert a `byte[]` to `string`. I have variable `K` an integer array and `pwd` a `byte[]` hence the the code bellow is giving me errors?

```
public void temp()
{
    int[] k = new int[256];
    byte[] pwd;
    int temp = 50;
    k[tmp] = pwd[(tmp % Convert.ToString((string)pwd).Length)];
}
```

Comment: @user1666620 Indeed it would be good duplicate if OP actually specify what is expected input and output. "Give me right code" is simply not enough to know what actual goal/problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably if it's in a byte array, it's encoded.  If you know what encoding, simply call `GetString` on the encoding.  For example, if it's UTF8 encoded:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pwd);
```